# How to attach the exact timestamp to "/gazebo/link_states" msg?

Tags: ros, gazebo, timestamp, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I made a simulated [environment](https://github.com/schizzz8/lucrezio_simulation_environments) and robot in Gazebo. Since Gazebo [publishes](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_comm) the robot pose w.r.t. the world, I'd like to use this information to "simulate" a localizer.

So far, this is what I did:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/tf.h>
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <gazebo_msgs/LinkStates.h>
#include <Eigen/Geometry>
#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>

class PoseBroadcaster{
public:
  PoseBroadcaster(ros::NodeHandle nh_):
    _nh(nh_){

    _camera_pose_sub = _nh.subscribe("/gazebo/link_states",
                                     1000,
                                     &PoseBroadcaster::cameraPoseCallback,
                                     this);
    _scan_sub = _nh.subscribe("/scan",
                              1000,
                              &PoseBroadcaster::scanCallback,
                              this);
  }

  void cameraPoseCallback(const gazebo_msgs::LinkStates::ConstPtr& camera_pose_msg){
    const std::vector<std::string> &names = camera_pose_msg->name;
    for(size_t i=0; i<names.size(); ++i){
      if(names[i].compare("robot::camera_link") == 0){
        const geometry_msgs::Pose camera_pose = camera_pose_msg->pose[i];
        _camera_transform=poseMsg2eigen(camera_pose);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  void scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr &laser_msg){

    ros::Time stamp = laser_msg->header.stamp;

    tf::StampedTransform camera_tf;

    try{
      _listener.waitForTransform("/odom",
                                 "/camera_link",
                                 stamp,
                                 ros::Duration(0.5));
      _listener.lookupTransform("/odom",
                                "/camera_link",
                                stamp,
                                camera_tf);
    } catch (tf::TransformException ex){
      ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
    }
    Eigen::Isometry3f camera_transform = tfTransform2eigen(camera_tf);

    tf::Transform odom_to_map_tf = eigen2tfTransform(_camera_transform*camera_transform.inverse());
    _br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(odom_to_map_tf, stamp, "/map", "/odom"));
  }

  Eigen::Isometry3f tfTransform2eigen(const tf::Transform& p){
  ...
  }

  Eigen::Isometry3f poseMsg2eigen(const geometry_msgs::Pose &p){
  ...
  }

  tf::Transform eigen2tfTransform(const Eigen::Isometry3f& T){
  ...
  }

protected:
  ros::NodeHandle _nh;
  tf::TransformListener _listener;

  tf::TransformBroadcaster _br;

  ros::Subscriber _scan_sub;

  ros::Subscriber _camera_pose_sub;
  Eigen::Isometry3f _camera_transform;

};

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  ros::init(argc, argv, "pose_broadcaster_node");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  PoseBroadcaster dummy(nh);

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

In few words, what it does is to:

- listen to "/gazebo/link_states" and store the last pose
- subscribe to "/scan" topic
- when a scan is received, listen to the camera pose at that time istant and publish the odom->map transform to "close" the tree

The main problem is that there is a delay between the moment the callback is executed and the laser scan timestamp. So, what should happen is that the pose that I get from Gazebo is more new w.r.t. to camera_link->odom transform.

A better solution would be to use `message_filters::Synchronizer`, but since gazebo_msgs/LinkStates is not stamped, this is not possible.

My question is: is it possible (perhaps through a Gazebo plugin) to attach a timestamp to the gazebo_msgs/LinkStates message?

Of course also better solutions are welcome :)

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295047/how-to-attach-the-exact-timestamp-to-%22/gazebo/link_states%22-msg?/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2018-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wouldn't this be a job for `gazebo_ros_p3d`? See #q222033.

---

Edit:

> No. This publishes the robot odometry. Which is different from the robot pose wrt the gazebo world.

The code seems to indicate otherwise. See [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/905146560772a80f76d9c595b6d7346067de24a1/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_p3d.cpp#L309-L312). The `pose.position.{x, y, z}` elements do not get calculated, but are initialised from the [world pose](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/905146560772a80f76d9c595b6d7346067de24a1/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_p3d.cpp#L267) of the configured link.

<del>If you set the `gaussianNoise` parameter to 0, it should be absolute ground truth (ie: pose in Gazebo world).</del> not even strictly necessary: noise is only added to linear and angular velocity estimates. But might be nice to do still if you want to use this as input to another node that takes [covariance](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/905146560772a80f76d9c595b6d7346067de24a1/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_p3d.cpp#L333-L348) into account.

Other answers (such as #q258748) also seem to confirm/suggest that.

---

Edit2:

> I agree with you that this plugin is publishing the world pose of the robot. Nevertheless, if I run it (inserting the lines specified in #q258748 in my urdf) I don't have a tf between /map and /odom frame which is what I really need.

Getting the odometry data out of Gazebo is only the first step. If you got that working, you should be able to use [fake_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/fake_localization) to do the rest.

The `base_pose_ground_truth` subscription would get its data from the `p3d` plugin.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on 2018-06-25**:
No. This publishes the robot odometry. Which is different from the robot pose wrt the gazebo world.

**Comment by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on 2018-06-26**:
I agree with you that this plugin is publishing the world pose of the robot. Nevertheless, if I run it (inserting the lines specified in #q258748 in my urdf) I don't have a tf between /map and /odom frame which is what I really need.